# Div innerHTML not updating during jquery ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, html

I am facing a problem while updating a DIV's html.
The HTML Code for the Div is;

```html
<div id="divforlog" 
     style="z-index:200000; overflow:auto;
     position:fixed; width:400px;
     height:300px; border:solid 2px gray;
     padding:10px; background-color:#F1F1F1">
</div>
```

OnClick of a button I call a code which shows this hidden div. And then takes an array of, a string which contains page Ids. For each ID I call an ".ashx" page using jquery and on success update the div's html. This all works fine in Firefox but not in other browsers(Chrome and IE). at the end of all function , I hide the div using jquery "slideUp" method. This sliding works in firefox, IE and chrome and shows all the inner html of the div before disappearing. SO my main problem is that the div is not shown up and updated. In Javascreipt there is also a div's reference which is used for progress bar and it also doesn't show in IE and Chrome.

JavaScript Code is as below:

```js
var progress = 0;
var totalpages;
var logstring = '';

function getProgressBarValue() {
  var s =
    '<span style="text-align:center;display:block">' +
    Math.round($('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value')) +
    '%</span>';
  return s;
}

function UpdateProgressBar(arg) {
  if (arg == 0) {
    var pvalue = (progress / totalpages) * 70;
    $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', pvalue);
  } else {
    $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 100);
  }
}

function getPageName(PageID) {
  return PageName; //string
}

function DisplayLogDiv() {
  $('#divforlog').css('display', '');
  $('#divforlog').css('top', 300);
  $('#divforlog').css('left', 300);
  $('#divforlog').html('');
  $('#divforlog').slideDown();

  $('#progressbar').css('top', 280);
  $('#progressbar').css('left', 300);
  $('#progressbar').show();
  $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 0 });
  $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 0);
  logstring = '';
  progress = 0;
  totalpages;
}

function AddLog(logstr) {
  $('#divforlog').html(getProgressBarValue() + logstring);
}

$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  DisplayLogDiv();

  $('#CustomerDetails').show();
  var PageIDs; //it is from some hidden field
  PageIDs = PageIDs + ',';
  var pageArray = PageIDs.split(',');
  totalpages = pageArray.length - 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < pageArray.length; i++) {
    //loop start here
    if (pageArray[i] != '') {
      progress = progress + 1;

      $.ajax({
        contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        data: somedatatobepassed,
        url: 'PublishIntermediate.ashx',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {}
      });

      UpdateProgressBar(0);
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
    contentType: 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    data: somedatatobepassed,
    url: 'PublishIntermediate.ashx',
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      UpdateProgressBar(100);

      AddLog(data);
    }
  });

  $('#CustomerDetails').hide();
  $('#divforlog').slideUp(500);
  $('#progressbar').slideUp(500);

  return false;
});
```

Regards
Ulfat Hussain

Comment: Could you please remove all the extra logging & starred lines from your wall of code? it will be easier for use to debug.

Comment: I have removed extra logging and starred lines.

Answer (score 0):

These codes

```
$('#CustomerDetails').hide();
$('#divforlog').slideUp(500);
$('#progressbar').slideUp(500);
```

inside your ajax success state,